# Eliminar QueryString

Tags: javascript, asp

tengo este pequeño inconveniente.
en un programa que estoy modificando se mandan 2 parámetros como un QueryString y se recuperan.

```
dim WorkOrder  : WorkOrder  = request.querystring("workorder")
dim CustomerPO : CustomerPO = request.querystring("customerpo")
```

quiero que al momento de darle click a un boton de búsqueda estas variables desaparezcan o dejarlas como cadena vacía("").
Estoy intentando utiliza javascript para ello, para detectar cuando se presiona ese boton:

```
response.write vbcrlf & "</script>"
response.write vbcrlf & "function recibir(){"
response.write vbcrlf & " var prueba = 
document.getElementById('txtWorkOrder').value;"
response.write vbcrlf & "console.log(prueba);"
response.write vbcrlf & "}"
response.write vbcrlf & "</script>"
```

pero no tengo mucha experiencia con ASP clasico, algien que me pueda hechar una mano?.
gracias

Comment: alguien que pueda echarme la mano??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que hice, fue realizar una consulta con SUM en la BD y realizando esa consulta con las String Query como parámetros en la condición Where.

Si se cumplía la condición y retornaba un valor mayor a 0 existían datos y mandaba esas String Query sin problemas, si el valor era mayor que 0 esas variables las limpiaba, las dejaba como cadena vacía("")